# Ошибка в применении bind

Tags: bind, tcl

Код:

```
entry  .entry   -textvar a
bind   .entry <Return> {Vvod a; continue }
pack   .entry   -side left

proc Vvod {a} {
global u
set u [format "%d" $a]
puts stdout "u = $u"
}
```

При выполнении выдаётся следующий текст -

```
expected integer but got "a"
expected integer but got "a"
    while executing
"format "%d" $a"
    (procedure "Vvod" line 3)
    invoked from within
"Vvod a"
    (command bound to event)
```

Как исправить ошибку?  ...

Answer (score 0):

Процедура "Vvod" вызывается со строкой "a", а не со значением переменой $a. Т.е. строку:

```
bind   .entry <Return> {Vvod a; continue }
```

нужно исправить как:

```
bind   .entry <Return> {Vvod $a; continue }
```